# No axis named length for object type, trying to sort based on length of dataframe and mask it to the second datafram

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, masking

I have 2 dataframes that I want to sort the values of the first dataframe by the string length which I used **str.len()** for then sort the second data frame based on the index of the second dataframe I'm trying to use **pandas.masking** but gives me error any advices ?
index of both dataframes are matching.
my code

```
wdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, nrows=0).columns[0]
skip = int(wdata.count(' ') == 0)
wdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip)

length= wdata['sentences'].str.len().sort_values()
print(length)
sort= wdata['sentences'].sort_values('length', ascending=True, inplace=True).any(axis=1)
df=sort

print(df)

df2 = pd.read_csv(fileinput, nrows=0).columns[0]
skip = int(df2.count(' ') == 0)
df2 = pd.read_csv(fileinput, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip)
newdata2 = df2[df2.sort(df.index)]
print(newdata2)

----------------------
#first dataframe example 
----------------------
#how are you 
#I want to die
#I was home
#I went to sleep at work
#he have a bad reputation
#it was me who went to him 
#have  good sleep home
#yes
#I'm good

----------------------
#second  dataframe example 
----------------------
#halaw kuy bashii
#damawe bmrm 
#la malawa bum
#la esh nustm 
#aw kabraya bash nya 
#awa mn bum chum bo lay
#xaweki xosh basar bba la malawa
#bale
#mn bashm
```

the output I expect is

[image]

[image]

the errors I'm getting

```
raise ValueError("No axis named {0} for object type {1}".format(axis, cls))
ValueError: No axis named length for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

what am I doing wrong any ideas to solve it please ?

Comment: What code return error?

Comment: ``` sort= wdata['sentences'].sort_values('length', ascending=True, inplace=True).any(axis=1)``` and  last line of masking I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first use [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) for positions of sorted values, so  then pass to [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
idx = wdata['sentences'].str.len().argsort()
df = wdata.iloc[idx]
print (df)
                   sentences
7                        yes
8                    Im good
2                 I was home
0               how are you 
1              I want to die
6      have  good sleep home
3    I went to sleep at work
4   he have a bad reputation
5  it was me who went to him
```

If want select one column to Series:

```
sentences = df['sentences']
```

For second use same, if same index values like `wdata`:

```
newdata2 = df2.iloc[idx]
```

Comment: first one works fine but for second dataframe output is wrong the id should be masked from the first dataframe because both dataframes has  sequence to sequence sentence so I need to keep them in same  sequence

Comment: @programmingfreak - Can you check if `newdata2 = df2.iloc[idx]` working?